# could not understand including the header file

Tags: c++

```
#include "Ser.h"
#include ".\ser.h"
```

Is this .\ser.h is an executable of Ser.cpp...When right clicked on it and when pressed "open the document .\ser.h" its going to the Ser.h file...

Why does they again include the executable file(./ser.h) as header file.... isnt the header file(Ser.h) enough to get all the delarations needed to be defined in.

Comment: Wha is your OS. Windows, I guess? Windows has case-insensitive file names.

Comment: And what "executable file" you're talking about, I don't get it

Comment: Maybe taking advantage of a platform-specific filename handling. Give more context where you are seeing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.\ser.h` is *not* an executable file, it's simply another header file.

In systems where file names are case-irrelevant (and this seems likely here since it's using the Windows path separator `\`), it may well be just including the same file twice.

If include guards are used correctly, that won't matter. If case *is* relevant, they're most likely two *different* files.

I say "may" since the order of searches for header files, and even the mapping of the *header-names* to headers or files, is implementation defined and `xyz.h` and `./xyz.h` may be found in different places because of this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of telling for sure without knowing what your include path is. This is likely just including the same header file twice on a case insensitive platform such as Windows. Which is probably a mistake but a harmless one because of include guards (those `#ifdef` at the beginning and end of the file).

It seems as if you are having trouble understanding the purpose of header files. There is no such thing as *the* header file. A header file is just the place where functions and classes are *declared* but usually not *defined*. So if `ser.cpp` uses some function that is defined in `common_functions.cpp`, you should include the apropriate header - it will usually be called `common_functions.h`.

Be aware that, as for almost anything in the C or C++ world, there are plenty of exceptions, but the above holds true most of the time.

Comment: But ifdef is not used ... both the header files are used one after the another.

Comment: @Beata Yes, but it is very unusual for a header file not to have include guards. I can't think of a single legitimate reason for that.

Comment: some headers are designed to be included multiple times, with different behaviour depending on which preprocessor macros are defined at the time. `<cassert>` is an example from the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

The *./ser.h* is not an executable file.  Please keep in mind, file extensions ending in *.h* are generally header files.

If your platform is windows you will find executable files taking the file extension *.exe*.

One *Ser.h* file **is** enough to receive all the declarations, so you do not need two of the same header files.